# cURL returns same results with different query

Tags: php, curl

cURL returns same results with different query from Ajax.
if I copy the query in the url field of the browser, it works and returns correct results.
test.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; Charset=iso-8859-1");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1); // don't use a cached version of the url

$query = $_GET['query'];
$source = $_GET['source'];
$startDate = $_GET['startDate'];
$endDate = $_GET['endDate'];

if($query != ""){ $query = '%20AND%20' . $query ;}

$req = '...:['. $startDate .'T00:00:00Z%20TO%20'. $endDate .'T00:00:00Z]%20AND%20origin:'. $source . $query;


$curl1 = curl_init($req);

curl_setopt($curl1,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl1,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($curl1);

echo $result;
```

script.js

```
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'test.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache:false,
                    data: {'query': query, 'source': source, 'startDate': startDate, 'endDate': endDate, 'interaction': interaction},
                    success: function(source){
                        data = source;
                        loadTable();
                    },
                    error: errorAjax
                });
```

Comment: Line 2 in js code:`url: 'test.php',`.

Comment: This is not the problem.

Comment: What does the URL look like that your PHP script creates, are you sure the values are being passed through properly?

Comment: if I copy the query ($req) in the url field of the browser, it works and returns correct results.